# Can't Run Playwright Chromium

Tags: node.js, typescript, firefox, chromium, playwright

- I want to execute tests via chromium.
- I already set chromium file path to in /C:.
- Firefox runs properly but I couldn't run chromium somehow.
- "npx playwright install" doesn't work for me I think because of company privacy policy(Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND playwright.azureedge.net).
- Typescript, Windows, Local pc.

Chromium shown up for a second but closed instantly.

**Error: browserContext.newPage: spawn UNKNOWN**

```
launchOptions: {
      executablePath: '***/ms-playwright/chromium-1076/chrome-win/chrome.exe',
      //executablePath: '***/ms-playwright/firefox-1422/firefox/firefox.exe',            
    },

projects: [

    {
      name: 'Login Test',
      testMatch: /.*webtests.Login.test.ts/,
      use: {
        browserName: 'chromium',
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
      },
```